# SAS: How to create a variable like 1,2,3,4,...,N

Tags: sas

I need to introduce a time trend to a regression model for a course but have no idea how to create a variable that's just (1,2,3,4,...,108). In R or Python I would just create an empty vector of 0's and then loop through to fill them with the loop index but I have no clue how to do it in SAS.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data want;
    set have;
    time_trend+1;
run;
```

SAS is an inherently looping language. The code above does four things:

1. Read a row
2. Add 1 to a variable called `time_trend`
3. Output the row to a dataset named `want`
4. Read the next row and execute the statements again

SAS automatically initialized the variable `time_trend` for us at compilation, so we do not need to declare a length or type. SAS assumes it is a numeric variable by default.

The statement `time_trend+1` is a special shortcut of the below logic:

```
data want;
   set have;
   retain time_trend 0;

   time_trend = time_trend + 1;
run;
```

Comment: Actually the equivalent assignment statement to mimic the SUM statement would use the SUM() function instead of  simple + operator.  Doesn't make any difference in this specific example since neither the variable nor the value added could be missing.  But in general use of the SUM statement either value might be missing when it runs and SUM() and + operate on missing values differently.

Comment: I was very skeptical at first but this worked! I didn't include all of the details but I had a data read-in and I simply wrote t+1 and it worked. It's a bit different from R and Python but I'm slowly getting the hang of this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! It's a unique little shortcut statement in SAS. If you've programmed in C or C++ before, it's analogous to saying `i++` in a loop.

Comment: Could you explain what the "set have;" statement is doing in this code?

Comment: `have` is a dataset. `set have` reads rows from the dataset.